# How many boats have been found encased in ice but still accessible?

Tags: boats, cold-weather, sailing, sea, ice

I was watching [*National Treasure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Treasure_(film)) again today and the scene in which Cage and his team discover and explore the *Charlotte* made me curious. They find the ship buried under ice and snow, yet, though everything is coated in a layer of ice, the interior is intact and not flooded. It has made me wonder if that has happened in real life, if it's even possible, and how often such a thing occurs.

Comment: Is the boat encovered in ice above land or above the sea?

Comment: If Shackleton were around I'm sure he would comment... But, ice moves, and the boat would not survive any long period unless maintained. Getting 'frozen in' is not a joke to mariners.

Comment: Most such entrapped boats sink, such as Franklin's *HMS Terror* and Shackleton's *HMS Endurance*, although they were found intact.

Comment: See "North to the Night" by Alvah Simon, who sailed north in a fairly small boat with his wife and a cat.  He spent the winter on his boat near Devon Island with the cat (his wife had to be evacuated because her father was dying)  (or an island close to Devon Island), (northeast Canada).  The ice gripped the boat, tilted the bow up,  and would have sunk it, but Simon managed to free and right the boat.   The cat saved his sanity.